# Unknown data in Parser.php

Tags: php, symfony, parsing, yaml

I use symfony 3, FosUserBundle, vichUploadBundle and EasyAdminbundle.
My issue:
I have an invalid YAML error when I add the fields line in app/config.yml:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        User: AppBundle\Entity\User
            list:
                fields:
                    - { property:'avatar', type:'image', base_path: '%app.path.avatar%'}
```

Indeed, I've got this:

> **ParseException**
>   A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 122 (near " - { property:'avatar', type:'image', base_path: '%app.path.avatar%'} ").
>   in Parser.php (line 729)
>
> at Parser->parseValue('AppBundle\Entity\User', 2816, 'mapping')
>   in Parser.php (line 349)
>
> at Parser->doParse('User: AppBundle\Entity\User list: fields: - { property:\'avatar\', type:\'image\', base_path: \'%app.path.avatar%\'} ', 2816)
>   in Parser.php (line 478)

I think that the unquoted value is 2816, but I don't understand where these value are coming from?
If someone can help ... 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
  easy_admin:
        entities:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\User #implement this line
            list:
                fields:
                        - { property:'avatar', type:'image', base_path: '%app.path.avatar%'}
```

Instead of

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        User: AppBundle\Entity\User #here is the error
            list:
                fields:
                    - { property:'avatar', type:'image', base_path: '%app.path.avatar%'}
```

Comment: Could accept the answer or just vote up if you can't accept it ?